# Privacy: Is editing viewable by anyone else if I decide not to post it?

Tags: support

This question relates to privacy, in that one may wish to *not* post material even after tentatively typing it into the edit box. Prior to clicking "Post Your Question", I notice there's often a "draft saved" message. Is any of the material viewable by anyone else at any time if I decide not to post it?

Comment: As far as I know, drafts are only saved to your cookies, so no.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Are you saying that drafts are only accessible from the same computer?

Comment: @Phira: again, as far as I know. I could easily be wrong about this. In any case, I've looked at the complete SE databases before and I don't remember seeing drafts stored anywhere in them.

Comment: [Related meta.SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/66238#66238)

Comment: The drafts are saved on the SE servers, but they are not visible to any other user.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks for the link -- in a comment on the accepted answer there, the moderator !waffles states that the storage of drafts is done server-side.

Comment: @Fabian: May I ask what is your source for the part about the saved drafts not being visible to any other user (e.g., moderators)?

Comment: @res Of couse the SE developers have access, they can directly read the database anyway. I'm a mod on another SE site and I never saw any option to see the saved drafts of anyone else, and as there is absolutely no need for that information to moderate it wouldn't make sense for SE to implement it.

Comment: @Qia I often use drafts to transfer text between machines, so they must in fact be saved on SE, not in machine-local cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the drafts (we only support one per question, one per answer, per user) are not visible to anyone but you.

They are saved on the server so as Bill pointed out, you can see a draft across multiple machines.